# Cannot connect to local DB at another PC. ASP .NET MVC4

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an mvc 4 database application on "PC1".  I just have chosen  by right click "Database SQL Server" and created **Entity Framework** with Database First approach. It works okay at "PC1". But when I copied my project to another PC, then the project failed.

**I do not have an SQL Server at the PC. I just copied the mvc 4 project with local database.**

*The error is: "...(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"*

I suppose that I should rewrite connection string. I've done this steps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873188.aspx
And I have tried to change a connection string from:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestApplication-20140918110411;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="CustomerDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UserModel.csdl|res://*/UserModel.ssdl|res://*/UserModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\CustomerDatabase.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="CustomerDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UserModel.csdl|res://*/UserModel.ssdl|res://*/UserModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\CustomerDatabase.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

To:

I have added name of PC(TomPC) to connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.TomPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestApplication-20140918110411;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="CustomerDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UserModel.csdl|res://*/UserModel.ssdl|res://*/UserModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.TomPC\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\CustomerDatabase.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="CustomerDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UserModel.csdl|res://*/UserModel.ssdl|res://*/UserModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.TomPC\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\CustomerDatabase.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

However, it fails with the same error.
 I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer. The application could not connect as connection string should be modified as LocalDB:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TestApplication-20140918110411;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="CustomerDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UserModel.csdl|res://*/UserModel.ssdl|res://*/UserModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\CustomerDatabase.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />    
 </connectionStrings>
```

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

Answer (score 3):

You will also need to ensure that TCP/IP is enabled in SQL Server config on TomPC, and also open up port 1433 (the default port, but it might be different, e.g. if there's more than one instance of SQL running on that PC).

Comment: 1. I haven't found a such option to enable TCP/IP in VS2012. It is a local database created from VS 2012 template. 2. I cannot find where I can open up a port 1433 in VS 2012(as I use local database).

Comment: This happened to fix the issue for me instantly, thank you!

I recently changed my router configuration which caused me to need to start forwarding ports.

Answer (score 1):

Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS

The . means "localhost" or 127.0.0.1

So adding the . means localhost\SQLEXPRESS or 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS

You need to change it to:

Data Source=TomPC\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: in "DefaultConnection" or "CustomerDatabaseEntities"?

Comment: I've tried recently to change it: Data Source=TomPC\SQLEXPRESS; However, i was with the same error:"provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

Comment: On top you must enable network on SqlExpress AND tell the firewall to accept the port, or you have no chance to even talk to the server.

Comment: It's in the SQL Express settings. This is installed with vs.net 2012 and not a part of it (its separate). Google how to do this, it's the same for every setup

Comment: @user3036342 I cannot modify full path in the SQL Express Settings. It is unavailable.

Comment: @TomTom, I do not have the firewall at this PC. I turned off the firewall.

Comment: @StepUp You don't have to modify the path or check the firewall. Google "How to access SQLExpress remotely", it will guide you through on how to setup SQLExpress to enable TCP/IP and get remote connections going

Comment: @user3036342, Guys, I do not have an SQL Server at the PC. I just copied the mvc 4 project with local database.

Comment: @3036342, I just copied name from VS.